# How can I upgrade docker container with Oracle 12c to Oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, upgrade, oracle12c, oracle19c

When I create my container base on Oracle 12c image, I use command:

```
docker run -d -it --name oracleDB -p 1521:1521 store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

Now how can I upgrade this container to Oracle 19c ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find Oracle dockerfile and source in their official github repository
[official github repository](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance).
This repo has a [19.3 version](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/19.3.0).

I think the best solution for your problem is:

1. backup your 12c data with datapump (expdp)
2. run a 19c container
3. import your 12c backup (impdp) in your fresh 19c container.